# how to use redline in jmeter master-slave

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, master-slave

does anyone know about using redline 13 using jmeter . I want to use 7 servers because I use master-slave, there is a way. I want to ask what is the right way to use redline 13 because there is no platform that provides complete ways

how to use master-slave jmeter and use redline 13 correctly